# Pushing data to database subdocument arrays from POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I can't figure out how to add data to a mongoose sub-document when I create a new schema from the client side. The only data that gets sent over to the data base is the data that is not nested inside another schema/array.

I'm using MongoDB with Mongoose for my database and NextJS as my both my front and back end.

I've haven't been able to find a way to get this working yet. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the back end route:

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req;
  switch (method) {
    case "POST":
      try {
        const workout = req.body;
        const newWorkout = new Workout({ ...workout });
        await newWorkout.save();
        res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: newWorkout });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      }
      break;
```

This is the mongoose schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const reqString = {
  type: String,
  required: true,
};

const WodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  exerciseName: reqString,
  repCount: reqString,
});

const exerciseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  workoutName: String,
  workoutContent: [WodSchema],
});

const WorkoutSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  workout: [exerciseSchema],
  // timestamps: true,
});

module.exports =
  mongoose.models.Workout || mongoose.model("Workout", WorkoutSchema);
```

This is the front end post request (only `name` gets sent to db):

```
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [workoutName, setWorkoutName] = useState("");
  const [exerciseName, setExerciseName] = useState("");

  const editProgram = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/workouts/`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, workoutName, exerciseName }),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: `workout` is a subdocument array, you need to format the data you're passing to it in `new Workout()` accordingly.

Comment: do you have an example of what that would look like?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
case "POST":
      try {
        const workout = req.body;
        const newWorkout = new Workout({
          name: workout.name,
          workout: {
            workoutName: workout.workoutName,
            workoutContent: {
              exerciseName: workout.exerciseName,
              repCount: workout.repCount,
            },
          },
        });
        await newWorkout.save();
        res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: newWorkout });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      }
```